# Windows Azure Error when publishing/ packaging

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I get an error when I'm trying to publish my web roles. I'm using VS2012 with Azure SDK 1.7.
Project runs without issues in the emulator. 
Error :

```
Error   79 The target "PipelineTransformPhase" does not exist in the project.
```

This error comes even with packaging.

Comment: What method are you using to publish?

Comment: I just right click the project and use the Publishing wizard. But later I found out that this issue comes when packaging the project.

Comment: I have found issues with the publishing tool so instead I use FTP to transfer the files from my local machine to the website in azure. Stopping and starting the website after upload will also release anything in the cache.

Comment: Actually even if you click package in the menu, it gives the same error. So I think there's something wrong with my project.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when you create a standalone MVC app the import declaration for Microsoft.WebApplication.targets in the proj file is slightly different than if you create a cloud service w/ an MVC web role. If you compare the two you'll notice a slight difference:

**Standalone MVC:**

```
<Import roject="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

**MVC Created as Web Role for Cloud Service:**

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

I just changed mine to use the VSToosPath and it resolved my issue.